# QML Warning: <Unknown File>: QML VisualDataModel: Error creating delegate

Tags: qt, qml, warnings

For the below MRE, I'm getting a warning message:

> Warning: : QML VisualDataModel: Error creating delegate

Here's what I know:

- Running this on an external linux board produces this warning but running on desktop does not
- Lowering `model` item count causes warning to appear less and less
- `ApplicationWindow` must remain visible, `ListView > delegate` must attempt to set `background`, and `MyButton > background` must have an `id`

Any ideas as to what causes this warning? I looked around for the error message on the QML JIRA but I didn't find anything that looked *like this case*

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    ListView {
        model: ['a','b','c','d']

        delegate: MyButton {
            background: Rectangle {}
        }
    }
}
```

**MyButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Button {
    background: Rectangle {
        id: background
    }
}
```

Comment: My hunch here is that there is something that goes wrong whenever I try to replace an existing property that has an ID, i.e. the `background` already existing within `MyButton.qml`

Comment: Windows/ QtQuick 2.12 has no this warning message.